# Android Back button closes app instead of going to the previous Activity

Tags: java, android, button, back

I open my first activity, which is just a loader for the 2nd Activity, on the 2nd Activity there are buttons, one of which opens a 3rd Activity. If I hit back from the Third activity instead of going to the 2nd Activity is just closes the Application. Anyway to fix this?

Here is some code snippets:

```
    public void onSegmentStatusButtonClick(View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Segment status button clicked.");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegmentStatusActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segment_status);
    TextView txtView = (TextView) this
            .findViewById(R.id.segment_status_msg);
    txtView.setText(new String(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("data")));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.segment_status, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "Executing onStop().");
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling finish() in onStop() ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling `finish()` in your `onStop()`.  I'd suspect this is the cause.  `finish()` will indicate that you're done with the Activity and will subsequently trigger a call `onDestroy()` and remove it from your back stack.  Removing these calls should cause back navigation to behave how you expect.  Activities should only be finished if you don't plan on returning to them.

Comment: Thanks, I am fairly new to Android development and didn't know when to properly call that method. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! http://developer.android.com is a great site for reference, it has the official api documentation and a lot of useful articles and tutorials to help you along. It was invaluable when I was learning.  Just keep at it and you'll learn a ton!